# why track email opens as events and not as pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Since a while I've been playing around with the Analytics Measurement Protocol, and also used it in some test emails as described in this article:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email

But what puzzles me is that Google recommends to track email views as events, not as page views.

From one side I can see the point, but on the other hand in Google Analytics I get an alert stating that I have events without page views.

Can anyone answer me why it should be done that way, or what arguments are there that speak for it? Otherwise I could also just use the Measurement Protocol to send a page view.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why Google recommends this, but I rather suspect it's because you will skew some of your metrics if you use pageviews - an opened e-mail would count as a bounce, which in turn would bring down average time on site, pages per session etc. If you make opened e-Mail an event you can avoid this.